# Fidder not capturing Power Query traffic in MS Excel

Tags: excel, fiddler, powerquery, excel-2016

I'm trying to capture traffic from the Power Query request fetching the data from a web source in MS Excel. However, no request is showing up in fiddler.

I tried to capture the traffic from a webpage over wikipedia, the response comes back with tabular data. But nothing shows up fiddler related to the power query traffic.

However, fiddler is capturing traffic very well from browsers and non-browser like Postman. How can i connect fiddler to excel?

Answer (score 1):

For wikipedia, try closing and reopening Excel.

For localhost traffic, Fiddler might not be expected to capture that. If you navigate to http://localhost in the browser, do you see the capture? You could try connection to http://127.0.0.1 and maybe that will work?

Answer (score 0):

If the web site you are accessing uses HTTPS, then you need to enable capturing and decrypting HTTPS traffic in Fiddler. You can do this from the Options dialog in Fiddler.

Comment: i enabled that already. However, i m accessing http link over wikipedia and also tries http over my localhost content